# Lowercase textnumero

Tags: symbols

I'm trying to reproduce a title from an older book, which uses what it seems to be a lowercase numero sign (see image below). Is there a symbol like this in latex (or even unicode for that matter!)?

Currently I simply doing this: `n.\textsuperscript{o}` where the "o" is the lowercase letter "O".

[image: scan]

Comment: For sizing, you may prefer `n.$^\circ$`

Comment: Maybe also consider `\textordmasculine`? Although that is not what appears to be in the original.

Comment: @jja Hm... are you sure there is a tiny line under that?

Comment: Not in the original image you uploaded, @drozzy, for that one I'd have to go with `\circ`, like Steven suggested.  But I had to do something similar recently and I went with the one I mentioned, so I thought you might like to hear about it as well, as a possibility.

Comment: @jja thanks. That whole [package](http://home.online.no/~pjacklam/latex/textcomp.pdf) of commands is good looking - I'm going to keep it for future reference.

Answer (score 7):

From your question I take, that unicode is favorable to you. In that case, you might want to use the xetex or luatex engines which natively support unicode input.

Unicode has only one codepoint (u+2116) for the numero sign, which should only be used for cyrillic and asian, according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numero_sign), and incorporates a capital N.

According to the same source, it's Italian practice to write Numero as n+superscript lowercase underlined o, which can be replaced by "n." or n+Ordinal symbol , which is part of unicode as well: u+00AB.

Your source seems to mix these two replacement versions.

The following code shows the different possibilities (Numero sign, n.+Ordinal sign, n.+superscript o, n.+degree symbol, which would be the xetex equivalent of the \circ proposed in the comments) using the fonts TeX Gyre Pagella and STIXGeneral via `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
№ n.\kern-0.5bpº n.\kern-0.5bp\textsuperscript{o} n.\kern-0.5bp°

\setmainfont{STIXGeneral}
№ n.\kern-0.5bpº n.\kern-0.5bp\textsuperscript{o} n.\kern-0.5bp°
\end{document}
```

I added the kerning, because the o/ordinal symbol in the original source seems to be horizontally closer to the . than in the produced copy.

The result shows, that STIXGeneral uses an Ordinal sign without underlining, which seems to be the most appropriate to me. But this depends on the font as TeX Gyre Pagella uses an underlined Ordinal sign.

So n.+superscript o seems to be the most practical way to go.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, great answer. Also, great tip on kerning... Where did you find the "codepoint" for ordinal symbol? _P.S.: I use xetex, linux libertine font._

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_indicator