# Pluralized numero symbol

Tags: symbols, typography

So, there's a [few](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101734/lowercase-textnumero/101774#101774) [questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40564/latex-numero-sign) about the Numero symbol: `№`. However, I'd like to be able to *pluralize* it. I'm not a master of the text-positioning-adjustment tools; but here's what I've got so far:

```
\section*{№\kern-0.5bp\textsuperscript{s} 42–44}
```

[image]

Could anybody provide me with an improvement on this? Even better, perhaps as a `\numeros` or similar macro? :D

Comment: I wouldn’t pluralize it at all. It’s a symbol not a word. You won't pluralize the unit in 23m, will you?

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to just recreate it, i.e. write an "N" and then superscript and underline "os". @Tobi Pluralising would depend on countries, e.g. in France we always use plural for this symbol when it refers to several numbers.

Comment: @ienissei: Even if you use the symbol _№_ or only when using the abbreviation _No._ / _Nos._?

Comment: @Tobi We don't use the symbol because it has no plural, but we use superscripts and sometimes underlining, basically we reproduce it.

Answer (score 7):

Not convinced about the usefulness, but

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\numeros{N{\raisebox{0.2ex}{\textsuperscript{\underline{os}}}}}
\begin{document}
\section*{\numeros}
\end{document}
```

works:

[image: Numeros]

Answer (score 6):

There is no easy solution on this, as the font you have chosen does use some special "o" here. It is smaller. Just compare the letters "os" and you will see that the "o" from the numero symbol here has some other shape.

Therefore it will always look wrong if you just put an "s" to its side. I could scale the letter down in order to fit the height, but this would make the "s" too light.

This solution is absolutely hacky and is more meant to show that you should not go this way. If you want this still, write a feature request to Georg Duffner (https://github.com/georgd/EB-Garamond/issues) and ask for a plural form of his file `SFD/EBGaramond12-Regular.sfdir/uni2116.glyph`

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EBGaramond}

\begin{document}
№\raisebox{.10266ex}{\kern-.1em\fontsize{6.5}{6}\selectfont\shortstack{s\\[-.89ex]--}} 42–44 

% for comparison  
os
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very pretty!  Too bad there's no such symbol in Unicode.  This page is among the top hits in Google image search for pluralized numero symbol.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this question is inevitably font specific, but within a given font (and you'll have to hand adjust the metrics for each typeface), this approach should work.  I have used only *relative lengths* (ie `ex` and `em`) which means that the approach scales, and used `ulem` instead of stacking like the other answer, mainly because it allows for easier adjustment of the thickness of the line to fit the glyph of the typeface in question. The example below isn't perfect, but is at least workable for most cases (and there is frankly an effort/reward question for how precisely the `s` aligns with the rest of the glyph). The following works for *Minion Pro* at any size and for all weights/fonts (bold, italic, etc), and the approach taken should, in theory, allow for any font's glyph to be pluralized (after unfortunately painstaking adjustments):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=0.35in,paperheight=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\renewcommand{\ULdepth}{.375ex}
\renewcommand{\ULthickness}{.07em}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \newcommand{\numeros}{№\kern -.7ex\raisebox{.525ex}{\scalebox{.65}{\uline{\hskip 1ex s}}}}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}
\centering\numeros\\\large\numeros\\\itshape\numeros\\\bfseries\numeros
\end{document}
```

[image: 4 № glyphs with the tex additions]